# define variable within conditional whilst testing against in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to call a method within a conditional to test against but also store return in a var within the same conditional reducing the api calls?
ie something like this:

```
elseif( 
        ($auth_type = \proj101\user::getUserAuthType( $user_profile['email'] ) ) 
        && $auth_type != AUTH_TYPE_GOOGLE  
){
  //$auth_type now equals the function return and not just 'true'
```

Comment: If I have understood correctly, in your elseif condition you are defining the value of $auth_type to the return value of the getUserAuthType(...) function, and then checking to see if the newly returned value isn't equal to "AUTH_TYPE_GOOGLE". THis is probably theoretically possible, but it's bad practice to write PHP code this way, it requires spending at good moment looking at the code just to understand it, try seperating it into multiple if conditions.

Comment: This works but it's not good style. One reason is that a common typo is to use `=` where you really meant `==` so that someone (maybe your future self) looking at this code may, at first, mistake this for such a typo and then _correct_ it. It's better to use an extra line or two to write this in a way that will be clear and not cause any confusion.

Comment: Question - if the correct answer is `0`, why would the `elseif` ever be true?  I mocked this up and found that besides your operator precedence being incorrect ( assignment has _lower_ precedence than logical AND), if the answer really is `0`, you end up with essentially `elseif(0)` and that shouldn't be true!

Comment: Yup, i found that adding the extra parenthesis around the var & api call returns the value of the api call into the var instead of just setting the var to 1 aka true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can do that, you just have to get the order of operations right.  Since assignment has lower precedence than logical `&&`, you end up setting auth_type to the result of the `&&` operation.

Consider this simple example:

```
<?php
const AUTH_TYPE_GOOGLE = 1;
function userAuthTypeStub( $x ){
    return 2;
}
if( 0 ){
    // who knows what to do?
}
elseif(
    $auth_type = userAuthTypeStub( 0 )
    && $auth_type != AUTH_TYPE_GOOGLE
){
    echo "$auth_type\n" . userAuthTypeStub(0) . "\n";
}
```

you get

```
1
2
```

but if you fix the order of operations, you get what you expect:

```
<?php
const AUTH_TYPE_GOOGLE = 1;
function userAuthTypeStub( $x ){
    return 2;
}
if( 0 ){
    // who knows what to do?
}
elseif(
    ( $auth_type = userAuthTypeStub( 0 )  )
    && ( $auth_type != AUTH_TYPE_GOOGLE )
){
    echo "$auth_type\n" . userAuthTypeStub(0) . "\n";
}

2
2
```

Note I had to adjust the result of the function in both cases, because if `$auth_type` ends up being 0 in either case, the `elseif` evaluates to `false` and the output is never executed.  That's one of the reasons I agree with most of the criticisms being offered that it would make the most sense to set `$auth_type` and *then* test its value.

Some languages (namely: C, if I'm not mistaken) don't promise anything about the order of operations of both sides of a logical `&&`, so it may be safe to say that depending on the second from the first is a bad practice.  I think that may be for the optimizations possibly gained by reversing the order.  This certainly isn't C so maybe it doesn't matter, but it sure makes debugging harder!

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: thank you very much! yup, i am now writing the extra line of code then checking against the var.